# How to translate RPC_STATUS into HRESULT?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, error-handling, rpc

In my COM component I need to translate all errors into the most suitable `HRESULT` values possible. Currently if I call some RPC interface method (I call a MIDL-generated stub that in turn calls [NdrClientCall2()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374215(VS.85).aspx)) and the call fails I return `E_FAIL` which is not very convenient.

There's so-called [*facility* in HRESULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb401631.aspx). Can I use this?

I tried to do the following:

```
HRESULT RpcStatusToHresult( RPC_STATUS status )
{
     if( status <= 0 ) {
         return status;
     }
     return ( status & 0x0000FFFF ) | (FACILITY_RPC << 16) | 0x80000000;
}
```

Will this properly translate `RPC_STATUS` to meaningful `HRESULT`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RpcStatusToHresult(status) is equivalent to MAKE_HRESULT(1, FACILITY_RPC, status). 
HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(status) is equivalent to MAKE_HRESULT(1, FACILITY_WIN32, status).

I, like you, had guessed the former would be correct, but in practice, at least as far as getting a proper error message from FormatMessage() is concerned, the latter is what actually works.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, that looks the same as HRESULT_FROM_WIN32

Comment: In what context do you use it? For user mode you should be fine with `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32`, but for kernel mode the layout of both should be basically identical to `NTSTATUS` which in turn has an identical layout to `HRESULT`.

However, I think there is hardly any way for us normal people to use the kernel mode version, so the solution from sam will be fine.

Comment: Oh, and there are some RPC exceptions that will not map correctly with that macro FYI.

This is the reason from what I understand why the Windows RPC team doesn't have a HRESULT_FROM_RPCSTATUS(), meaning it would not always produce correct results, so they don't supply one in the SDK somewhere.